# Laravel Using nested with

Tags: laravel

I couldn't do what I wanted to do with Laravel, actually what I want to do is as follows,

I send `getTruck` id and list `truckHistory` with witdh, and I want to pull `trukInvoice` information with `truckHistory` `invoice_id`. But i am getting error where am i doing wrong?

Mysql Connection is as follows.
[image]

http://localhost:3000/truck/1

"trucks" table  column "plate"

"invoice_details" column "plate_no"

"invoice_details" column "invoice_id"

"invoice" column "id"

Truck Controller

```
public function getTruck($id)
    {
        $truck = Truck::find($id)->with([
            'truckHistory' => function($query){
//                return $query->with(['trukInvoice']);
            }
        ])->first();
        return $truck;
    }
```

Truck Model

```
public function companys()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class, 'company_id', 'id');
    }

    public function getCompanyNameAttribute()
    {
       return $this->companys()->first()->name;
    }

    public function truckHistory(){
        return $this->hasMany(InvoiceDetail::class,'plate_no','plate');
    }

    public function trukInvoice(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Invoice::class,'invoice_id','id');
    }
```

Comment: You can use dot annotation for with(), wouldn't with('truckHistory.truckInvoice') work? if it works i write up an answer :) But also why is invoice and history in the same model and you try to access them nested?

Comment: that is, when I enter the url "http://localhost:3000/truck/1", it seems that the details of all the invoice issued to the name of "truck" are listed, and I need to display the information of "INVOICE". I have to connect to the "invoice" table to find out "which detail belongs to which invoice"

Comment: but i dont think your relationship makes sense, why do you want to access it nested when it is in the same model? does truckhistory have an invoice id etc?

Comment: I want to tell you again,Whn the invoice is created, the infrmation of the invoice is recorded in the "INVOICE table" and the details of the invoice are recorded in "invoice_detail". the id of the vehicle selected in the extra invoice detail in the "TRUCK" table It records in "invoice_id" and "plate_no" columns in "INVOICE_DETAIL"
When I enter the Vehicle Detail, I list all the data that matches the "plate_no" in the "invoice_detail" table from the "plate" column of the Vehicle. Likewise, I want to connect the "invoice_id" in the "invoice_detail" to the "invoice" table and list the data there

Comment: I have added the image as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$truck = Truck::leftJoin('invoices', 'trucks.invoice_id', 'invoices.id')
    ->leftJoin('invoice_details', 'trucks.plate_no', 'invoice_details.plate')
    ->select('*')
    ->first();
```

or

```
$truck = Truck::with(['invoices' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('invoice_details', function ($q){
            $q->whereNotNull('invoice_details.plate');
        });
    }])->first();
```

Check the documentation on restraining [eager loads.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Where should I write this to the model?

Comment: write this to controller.

Comment: ok i am getting an error. I have to process by $id

Comment: `message: "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::addEagerConstraints does not exist.",…}
exception: "BadMethodCallException"
file: "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\YeniMuhasebe\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Macroable\\Traits\\Macroable.php"
line: 103
message: "Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::addEagerConstraints does not exist."`